# Better way to locate problems in a running Java application?

Tags: java, debugging, runtime

We have a few java applications (jars) running as backend server applications on localhost. These programs are inside a virtual box (RHEL 6.2).
After one of the jar's ran for 5 days, it stopped working. No exceptions were thrown (didn't see any output of the errors that could be caught in the catch block). To find out what caused this, we put in some `println's` and redirected output to a text file using the `>` operator on the commandline using shellscript.
After about 4 or 5 days, we faced a situation where we could see that the jar was still running, but it wasn't outputting anything to the text file or to the database to which the application was supposed to write entries.
Perhaps the textfile became too large for the virtual box to handle, but basically we wanted to know this:

How are such runtime problems located in Java? In C++ we have valgrind, Purify etc, but
**1. are there such tools in Java?

2. How would you recommend we output println's without facing the extremely-large-textfile problem? Or is there a better way to do it?**

Comment: Logging is the best way to output the status of your application. See `Log4J` or `SLF4J` logging libraries, which also have support of rolling the log file from making it becoming too large. Also in your application you should perform rolling if the file size increases than a threshold.

Comment: Also try to monitor your application using `JProfiler` or `VisualVM` to see the current memory and other vital status of application. That can also help you to see where the application is stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than printing to System.out how about using tools like log4j.  Log4J allows for logfile sizing, versioning and purging.

see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/

You may also want to re-consider your server architecture.

Answer (score 1):

> How are such runtime problems located in Java? In C++ we have
>   valgrind, Purify etc, but 1. are there such tools in Java?

There are lot of java profilers available, few are free as well. There is one called VisualVM, which comes along with java distribution. You can attach your process with profiler, but profilers will only help you find few problems such as memory leaks, cpu intenstive task etc

> 1. How would you recommend we output println's without facing the extremely-large-textfile problem? Or is there a better way to do it?

Sysout are not a good way to deal with this problem. Loggers such as log4j provides very roboust and easy to use API. Log4j also provides easy way to configure to roll over your log files, etc features